# After each push to Heroku I get 404 errors on images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am having issues with my Rails App on Heroku. [code-dojo.herokuapp.com](http://code-dojo.herokuapp.com)

After every push to heroku any images I uploaded with Carrierwave Gem return a 404 error message.

Do I need to precompile this folder or point to it ?

Does Heroku replace this folder with a blank one?

Should I create my app with all the images on locathost and then push the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku is [Read-only Filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem)

The following types of behaviors are not supported:
Caching pages in the public directory
Saving uploaded assets to local disk (e.g. with attachment_fu or paperclip)
Writing full-text indexes with Ferret
Writing to a filesystem database like SQLite or GDBM
Accessing a git repo for an app like git-wiki

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an external storage solution. You can accomplish this for example by using the `gem carrierwave-aws` instead of the `gem carrierwave`, with which you can configure an Amazon S3 bucket to store your images on...